# Read Windows text file on Linux --- MIME issues?

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding

I'm trying to read a file, of MIME type "appliaction/octet-stream" line by line via a Java application running on a Linux PC.  Clarification: "appliaction/octet-stream" was the result of running "file -ib file.txt" on Linux.

The file I'm trying to read was created on Windows XP.

I've called my file "file.txt".

On linux, "cat file.txt" displays the contents.  "cat -v" as well as vim shows the control characters.

When I run code to iterate through it via my Java application (using simple BufferedReader(FileReader) type of code), my output is unexpected.

Any approached I should take?  I tried converting the file using dos2unix, but no avail.

**EDIT**: the input file, when read through vim or "cat -v" is as follows:

```
[^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@]^@^M^@
```

The line simply says "System", but it seems the control characters are rendering the file unreadable via my Java app.

**UPDATE:** I ran my code using all available Character encodings, and it turns out that the readable CharSets were "x-UTF-16LE-BOM" and "COMPOUND-TEXT".  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Probably line endings. Linux/Unix use `\n`, Windows uses `\r\n`. Files themselves have no "mime type". mime is something that's wrapped AROUND files to explain what data type(s) is in them.

Comment: Use the same encoding to write and read the file and it should work fine...

Comment: 1) Elaborate on "output is unexpected" and give more on what exactly the file contains, and perhaps some code... 2) What does this have to do with MIME?

Comment: This is most likely an encoding or linebreak issue. On Windows the default linebreak is `\r\n` and the default encoding is `Latin 1`. On most Linux systems the default linebreak is `\n` and the default encoding is `UTF-8`.

Comment: I should clarify, the unexpected output is that the lines it reads are all blank, but the input file clearly has text on every line.

Comment: @dvnrrs, the input file, when read through vim or "cat -v" is as follows:

`[^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@]^@^M^@`

The line simply says "System".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file was written using the [UTF-16 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). To read this in Java, you'll just need to [specify that encoding in your reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098186/how-to-force-utf-16-while-reading-writing-in-java):

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

Comment: I've tried the above, and here's my results:

My InputStreamReader no longer recognizes new line characters, so it treats the entire file as one line. 

In addition, I still cannot read the file using new new encoding.

Comment: Also, perhaps I was unclear about the MIME type above.  What I meant was that when I ran "file -ib file.txt" on Linux, the result was "appliaction/octet-stream".

Comment: @cjtightpant Are you trying to read the file you converted with `dos2unix`? Don't; that will corrupt a file encoded in this way.

Comment: see my latest update.  I used the code you posted above with `x-UTF-16LE-BOM` as the Charset, and the text was readable.  Thanks!