# Why FileInputStream readline returns null when I set encoding to UTF-16?

Tags: java, encoding, bufferedreader, streamreader

It works fine with `UTF-8`, and it also works fine with `UTF-16` if I use different file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-16"));
```

If I replace `UTF-16` with `UTF-8` in above code, everything works as expected, why is that?

Suggested answer is different because I just need to read the file. Answer was simple, I can't read UTF-16 if the file is UTF-8.

Comment: What is the *exact* content of the file that is not read correctly? Is it encoded using using UTF-16? BE or LE?

Comment: It is right first line when I do `br.readLine();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force UTF-16 while reading/writing in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098186/how-to-force-utf-16-while-reading-writing-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the encoding of your files. UTF-16 can be encoded using Big Endian (UTF-16BE) or Little Endian (UTF-16LE). These are different.

This code works for four variants of the same file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        readAndPrint("/tmp/u-8.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        readAndPrint("/tmp/u-16.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
        readAndPrint("/tmp/u-16le.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
        readAndPrint("/tmp/u-16be.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-16BE"));
    }

    private static void readAndPrint(String filePath, final Charset charset) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), charset));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

On GNU/Linux you can check the encoding using the `file` tool:

```
/tmp % file u*.txt
u-16be.txt: data
u-16le.txt: data
u-16.txt:   Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with no line terminators
u-8.txt:    UTF-8 Unicode text
```

The content of these files are all different:

```
/tmp % cat u*.txt
����
����
������
üäöü
```

But using the above Java code, they can be read correctly. The output of my Java code is:

```
üäöü
üäöü
üäöü
üäöü
```

Comment: You must use the correct encoding, that's all. What is the encoding used for the file?

Comment: Make sense now... Thanks ;d